# how to insert php on jquery/javascript

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert PHP into jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451212/how-to-insert-php-into-jquery)

how to insert php on jquery/javascript ? for example

php

```
$tot =4;
```

javascript

```
$(function()

    if( can put php here? )
    eg : if( <?php tot > 4 ?> )
```

i want to put the php in 'if statement' ,it`s possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function() {
  if(<?=$tot?> > 4) {
    [...]
  }
});
```

The `<?=$tot?>` part will effectively `echo` your `$tot` variable in the javascript code. Beware that if `$tot` evaluates to `''` when converted to string, it could create a syntax error in javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`if (<?php echo $tot; ?> > 4)`